# Highlighting variables of function scope

Tags: haskell, emacs, syntax-highlighting

How to highlight function scope variables and/or local function names (names defined in the same file, excluding definitions) for any language or haskell in particular in Emacs?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of font-lock, the Emacs highlighting engine. A font-lock rule can be based on a regexp (which is useful in simple cases), a function call that, somewhat, behaves as a regexp search (but where you can use code to refine the search), or code that simply bangs in the highlighting. My package https://github.com/Lindydancer/lisp-extra-font-lock do this for local variables in lisp. Of course, lisp is easier to parse than Haskell, but it can give you a good starting point. If you plan to write the rules, please look at my `font-lock-studio` and `faceup` packages.